# Time Format Documentation

Tags: objective-c, documentation, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert the Twitter created_At timestamp to another timestamp using NSDateFormatter. However it took me a while to work out the date style for the timestamp.

Is there any documentation out there than includes all the codes/date styles that can be used with the NSDateFormatter?

P.S. Anyone that needs the style it is: eee MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two pieces of documentation to check out.  The first is the [Date Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). It gives an overview of all of the options and uses.  The other thing to check out is the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).  It's what NSDateFormatter uses for the formatting patterns and lists out what all the different date field symbols are.